# Swapping data in SQL

Tags: mysql

This is my data in the database

```
member_name    image_one    image_two    image_three
----------------------------------------------------
James             1             4             3         
Bruce             2             5             6
```

What I'm trying to do is swapping 4 with 2.

I have no idea how to write the SQL query.

I'm figuring out how to make an update query which can either swap the image either it is from image one or image two or image three.

Here is the example

```
UPDATE from member 
SET image_two = 2 
WHERE member_name = "James";

UPDATE from member 
SET image_one = 4 
WHERE member_name = "Bruce";
```

These query can only swap the image from `image_two` (James) with `image_one` (Bruce).

But what actually I'm looking for a query is which can swap directly if "from image id" and "to image id" are given. Hope you can understand my question.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you want to change existing data you use an `UPDATE` query

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: I have edited the post, hope you guys can now understand my question.

Comment: Im using MySQL.

Comment: Consider revising your schema, such that image_ids are stored in a separate table, together with the id of their respective member.

Comment: I don't understand 'swap directly if the image id is given' if this said 'swap directly if the imageS id is given' or the 'swap if the from image id and to image id are given' would make more sense to me. AND are there only ever three images columns?

Comment: P.Salmon, yeah that what im trying to say,sorry for misunderstanding caused.

Answer (score 0):

You may try an update join:

```
UPDATE member m1
INNER JOIN member m2
    ON m1.member_name = 'James' AND
       m2.member_name = 'Bruce'
SET
    m1.image_two = m2.image_one AND
    m2.image_one = m1.image_two;
```

Comment: Is it possible swap the image if the image id is given?

Comment: Edit your question and show us the actual data then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing from and to then you could firstly unpivot(subquery s) then pivot using case statements to switch from to to and to to from.

```
DROP table if exists t;
create table t
(member_name  varchar(20),  image_one int,    image_two int,    image_three int);
insert into t values
('James'  ,           1       ,      4      ,       3),         
('Bruce'  ,           2       ,      5      ,       2);

set   @from = 2;
set   @to   = 4;
select member_name,
         max(case when img = 1 then
              case when ino = @from then @to
                   when ino = @to then @from
                else ino
                end 
         end ) image_one,

         max(case when img = 2 then
              case when ino = @from then cast(@to as int)
                   when ino = @to then cast(@from as int)
                else ino
                end 
         end) image_two,
         max(
         case when img = 3 then
              case when ino = @from then @to
                   when ino = @to then @from
                else ino
                end 
         end) image_three

from              
(
select 1 as img,member_name, image_one as ino from t
union all
select 2 as img,member_name, image_two from t  
union all
select 3 as img,member_name, image_three from t 
) s   
group by member_name desc;

 +-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| member_name | image_one | image_two | image_three |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| James       |         1 |         2 |           3 |
| Bruce       |         4 |         5 |           4 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: May i know what ino stands for?

Comment: It's an alias , Have you not come across this concept yet? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)